# Apache + ModSecurity構成で Gaceful での再起動に失敗する場合がある

Tags: apache

Apache + ModSecurityを運用中のサイトで、攻撃があった際に遮断しApacheのGracefulを実行しています。
しかし、不定期にApacheのGracefulが失敗し、Apacheが停止したままサービスが運用できない状態に陥っています。
攻撃の回数があまりにも多いと稀にGracefulが失敗するとの情報提供があったのですが、これでは攻撃を防御できていないと同じで元も子もない状態です。

Gracefulが失敗した際に吐き出されるエラーログは以下となります。

エラー内容

```
[core:notice] [pid 9084] AH00060: seg fault or similar nasty error detected in the parent process
```

同じ状況で対策された方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか。
もしくは、Apache + ModSecurityに詳しい方でご助言いただけますと幸いです。

**サーバ環境**
CentOS 7.8.2003 (Core)
Apache 2.4.6
ModSecurity 2.9.2-1

#### 補足

上記のサーバは、サイバーセキュリティクラウド社の攻撃遮断くん（サーバセキュリティタイプ）を利用するために設定しております。
メーカーに確認しても、稀に落ちてしまうとの回答です。

様々なサイト等を調べても有益な情報がなく大変困っております。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: Apache は CentOS のパッケージをインストールしているのであればパッチバージョンまで記載してみてください。 (2.4.6 の後にもハイフンを挟んで数字が続くはずです)

Answer (score 0):

完全な回答にはならないかもしれませんが、調べてわかった範囲で回答してみます。

---

エラーメッセージで検索すると、例えば以下の記事がヒットします。

[apache が夜中に異常終了 (seg fault or similar nasty error detected)](https://qiita.com/kyotoisalsosnownight/items/a54066649dcce670e13f)

> 原因は おそらく Apache の [バグ](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1376835) です。
> バージョンによりますが、reload(graceful) で再起動を繰り返すと、再起動の何回目かに、今回のように落ちます。

上記の記事では logrotate のタイミングで Apache の再起動を繰り返すうちに問題が発生していたようですが、質問者さんの環境だと「攻撃の検知」で同様の問題が発生している可能性が考えられます。

お使いの CentOS は 7.8.2003 と少し古いバージョンなので、手っ取り早くは Apache の更新で解決するかもしれません。

参考までに CentOS **7.9.2009** 向けには (現時点での恐らく最新版として)
[httpd-2.4.6-95.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/httpd-2.4.6-95.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm.html) パッケージがリリースされているようです。